# GTX1060 Graphics card not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have a Gigabyte H370N-WIFI motherboard with i5-8600K and 16GB of RAM running Ubuntu 20.04.  It has been running well.  Yesterday, I tried to install a Zotac GTX1060 Mini graphics card and driver.  After installation and rebooting, I found that the graphics card works, but keyboard and mouse are completely unresponsive.  If I shutdown and connect the display to Intel Integrated graphics and reboot, everything works once again (even while the GTX1060 and drivers are installed).  Zotac is, predictably, blaming the OS (or a possible hardware conflict).  Nothing in DMESG indicates a problem.  Removing the card ends the issue, but I was hoping to use it.  Has anyone encountered this issue?  And if so, could you advise me on how to go about resolving it.

Comment: Question is: How did you install it. Did you use the "Ubuntu" drivers or did you take code from the Nvidia site?

Comment: Initially, I used drivers from NVidia's site.  Then, after encountering the problem, I uninstalled them and tried Ubuntu's drivers - same result.  So finally, I tried an installer directly from Zotac (the graphic card maker).  All had the same result.

Comment: I would add that I do see an error in dmesg:
acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
That error has something to do with acpi and thus shouldn't be a factor here - and it is present whether I have the card and drivers installed or not.